# Are autocorrelation, heteroscedasticity and normality of residuals used in non-linear models?

Tags: r, autocorrelation, residuals, heteroscedasticity, nonlinear-regression

I have a very simple non-linear model:

```
lm(Y ~ poly(X, degree = 2), data=data)
```

The results I obtained are:

[image: model output from R]

My question is, to test the validity of the model, is testing for autocorrelation, heteroscedasticity and normal distribution of residuals relevant for non-linear models?

Answer (score 2):

You do **not** have a nonlinear model, you have a linear model with a polynomial predictor. So yes, this model is nonlinear in the predictor `x`, but it is linear in the unknown model parameters, and that is what is meant with a linear model.

So your model assumes that, around the parabolic expectation, there is a normal-distributed error term with zero expectation and constant variance.

So to your question:

> My question is, to test the validity of the model, is testing for
> autocorrelation, heteroscedasticity and normal distribution of
> residuals relevant for non-linear models?

Yes, yes, and yeas, all of those are potentially relevant for your **linear** model. And, if you had a nonlinear model with additive normal errors, those would still be relevant.